# error MSB4018: непредвиденная ошибка при выполнении задачи "GenerateResource"

Tags: c#

Проект проги полностью перекинул на другой комп, отредактировал там его (версии студии совпадают), потом перекинул обратно. Теперь не компилится. Выдает эту ошибку((

> 1>------ Сборка начата: проект: WindowsFormsApplication1, Конфигурация: Debug Any CPU ------
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018: непредвиденная ошибка при выполнении задачи "GenerateResource".
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018: System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018:    в Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResGenDependencies.GetResXFileInfo(String resxFile)
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018:    в Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.ShouldRebuildResgenOutputFile(String sourceFilePath, String outputFilePath)
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018:    в Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.GetResourcesToProcess(List`1& inputsToProcess, List`1& outputsToProcess, List`1& cachedOutputFiles)
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018:    в Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018:    в Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018:    в Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

Помогите, кто сталкивался с этим... Все что находил не подходило по стилистике

Answer (score 2):

Надо удалить папки Bin и obj из папки проекта и запутить заново.